Why my properties in my blazor wasm always become null when i submit the form
This is my code:
From what I can see, I am creating a new instance of the class, binding each attribute to the class in the form, then converting to JSON and printing. What am I missing?
@inject IIdentityService IdentityService;
@inject ErrorService ErrorService;

<div class=" w-full flex justify-center text-main  ">
    <div class="flex w-full">
        <div class="w-1/2 flex">
            <div class="w-full h-[100vh] bg-cover bg-center"
                 style="background-image: url('./images/identity/login.jpg')">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white p-8 w-1/2 rounded-lg pt-[10%] px-[5%]">
            <EditForm Model="RegisterModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" FormName="RegisterForm">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
                <ValidationSummary/>

                <!-- First Name and Last Name -->
                <div class="mb-4 flex justify-between">
                    <InputText
                        @bind-Value="FirstName"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        class="form-control mt-1 block w-[48%] px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                        required/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => FirstName)"/>

                    <InputText
                        @bind-Value="LastName"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        class="form-control mt-1 block w-[48%] px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                        required/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => LastName)"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Phone Number -->
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <InputText
                        @bind-Value="RegisterModel.PhoneNumber"
                        placeholder="Phone Number"
                        class="form-control mt-1 block w-full px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                        required/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => RegisterModel.PhoneNumber)"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Email -->
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <InputText
                        @bind-Value="RegisterModel.Email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        class="form-control mt-1 block w-full px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                        required/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => RegisterModel.Email)"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Password -->
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <InputText
                        @bind-Value="RegisterModel.Password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        class="form-control mt-1 block w-full px-6 py-4 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                        required/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => RegisterModel.Password)"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Register Button -->
                <div>
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="w-full inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm font-medium rounded-sm text-white bg-[#00205c] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 text-xl transition-all ease-out">
                        Register
                    </button>
                </div>
            </EditForm>

            <div class="w-full flex justify-between mt-3  ">
                <button class="hover:underline" type="button">
                    <NavLink href="/login">
                        Already Have An Account?
                    </NavLink>
                </button>
                <button class="hover:underline " type="submit">
                    <a href="">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "RegisterForm")]
    private RegisterFormModel RegisterModel { get; set; } = RegisterFormModel.Empty;

    private string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        RegisterModel.Username = $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

        var result = await IdentityService.Register(RegisterModel);

        if (result.IsFailure)
        {
            ErrorService.SetErrorMessage(result.ErrorTypes);
        }
    }


The Problem is when i bind the form value to the p tag, it still display my input value, but when i send the submit, it become null or i should say default value.
I also check it in the server and try to change the default value of the DTOs in the backend, so i can know when i send, the bind value in my blazor form is empty or null.
What can i do? the @rendermode dont work in blazor wasm or i just missing something
Edit: my problem also happen with all of property not only firstname/lastname
Edit2: My service
public class IdentityService(
    IHttpClientFactory factory,
    string baseUrl = nameof(IdentityService),
    string endpoint = "api/User"
) : BaseApiService(factory, baseUrl, endpoint), IIdentityService
{
    public async Task<Result> Register(RegisterFormModel registerModel)
    {
        var content = SerializeItem(registerModel);
        var result = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{Endpoint}/Register", content);
        return await HandleResponse(result);
    }

    public async Task<Result<LoginResponse>> Login(LoginFormModel loginModel)
    {
        var content = SerializeItem(loginModel);
        var result = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{Endpoint}/Login", content);
        return await HandleResponse<LoginResponse>(result);
    }
}
    protected static StringContent SerializeItem<TItem>(TItem item)
        where TItem : class
    {
        return new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }


My model:
public class RegisterFormModel
{
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public static RegisterFormModel Empty =>
        new()
        {
            Email = default,
            Username = default,
            Password = default,
            PhoneNumber = default,
        };
}



This issue is more likely happened in SSR. In SSR the input field has to be in the editform model.
    public class RegisterFormModel
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
...

        var content = SerializeItem(registerModel);
        var result = await Client.PostAsync($"{Endpoint}/Register", content);

 <InputText @bind-Value="RegisterModel.FirstName" ...
...
 <InputText @bind-Value="RegisterModel.LastName" ...

And need use following pattern to initilize the model
    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "RegisterForm")]
    private RegisterFormModel RegisterModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => RegisterModel ??= new RegisterFormModel();

-------------------update--------------------
Inside this page, add a testValue to check if the Value dispaly changed correctly.
@testValue

@code {
    private string testValue { get; set; } = "test";
...
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {

        testValue = FirstName + RegisterModel.PhoneNumber;

------------------------update2----------------------
The PostAsJsonAsync method doesn't match the [FromForm] attribute which accept MultipartFormDataContent. There are 2 ways to do this post.

Delete [FromForm]

public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Register.Commond commond)

then use PostAsync instead.
            var content = SerializeItem(registerModel);
            var result = await Client.PostAsync($"{Endpoint}/Register", content);


Still use FromForm (in case you cannot change the api)

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var stringContent = new StringContent(registerModel.Username, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Add(stringContent, "UserName");
            stringContent = new StringContent(registerModel.Email, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Add(stringContent, "Email");
            stringContent = new StringContent(registerModel.PhoneNumber, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Add(stringContent, "PhoneNumber");
            stringContent = new StringContent(registerModel.Password, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Add(stringContent, "Password");

            var result = await client.PostAsync($"{Endpoint}/Register", content);


my modal name is not just first name and last name, it is username so i bind it when submit, but the problem happen with every property not just first name and last name

@Nam I see the registerModel doesn't have firstname and lastname property.  So Do you mean the whole registerModel is empty? And Even the firstname and lastname?

Could you post the RegisterFormModel code?

yes, as you see in the handlevalidsubmit, i have bind the first name + lastname to username, but when i submit, the whole properties (include password, phonenumber...) of the model is null (which is the default value)

@Nam Is RegisterFormModel  static?  Could you share the model code?

i have share it in my edited post, can u review it again

the bad request with my error code format is return so there is no any problem with my api, i also test it with open api swagger

@Nam I actually tested with your code without any issue. Do you mean the RegisterModel is empty before  var result = await IdentityService.Register(RegisterModel); ? Then this will have nothing to do with identityservie.  Do you use a WebAssembly standalone project or Blazor web app?

@Nam This issue is more likely a SSR behaviour. Could you confirm what template are you using and is it an SSR page?

I can confirm that my blazor is wasm because of my program.cs, but as you said, i just know that the model is empty when send to my api but i cant check that model is empty when pass to the identityservice or not

@Nam so it is a single client side project with no backend serverrender mode blazor project, right?

https://imgur.com/a/SgjweFw
i think i can confirm that it not blazor server

Yes, it is just a client side, without backend, my backend is asp.net core api
https://imgur.com/a/PSsvJx7
i have debug and it is null value in all of my properties

@Nam Sure, its WASM standalone. Because there's no way the value is empty when binding in this mode. After see your endpoint. I doubt the null happens when post. Does the postAsJsonAsync with [FromForm] really match? Let me do I test and come back for you. And you could check if the RegisterModel by some little trick as I will update my answer.

Thanks for your help so much, i will wait.

Ah, i also try both with asjson or not, it not working as well.

@No worries. Just check the RegisterModel with my update. Sorry I maybe back 1 hour for a lunch. You could check my response later.

Hi, I have done the things you told me before, there is the result, i think the problem is serialize but i dont know how to fix it https://imgur.com/a/uNoS4gM

@Nam I also think the issue is the post procedure. You could try my last update.

It work, thanks for your help.

@Quiang Fu I think the problem is wrong media type of the body, so i change to like you and it work perfectly, thank u so much

@Nam Glad to hear that. Would you help to follow the instruction https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

thank u, i have accepted this answer, i am not allow to upvote it and i dont know why, haha.
